# AWS Rehost detailed steps

Tags: amazon-web-services, rehosting

I am planning to Rehost (Lift-and-Shift) one of the on-premise application to AWS cloud. I want to understand if the below steps are in correct sequence:

1. Specify Migration Goals
2. Analyse migration services
3. Discover components to migrate
4. Identify data to migrate
5. setup cross environment connectivity
6. Test
7. Backup data and application
8. Migrate application components
9. Replicate application data
10. Test components and application functionality

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your question, it seems that this question is picked up from Coursera's AWS specialization course. If it's so, you must try to solve that by your self. And if you fail to, and want to know the answers to learn, the answers were available in the Developer Tools.

If that's not the case, the correct sequence will be:

```
   1. Specify Migration Goals
   2. Identify data to migrate
   3. Discover components to migrate
   4. Analyze migration services
   5. Identify migration plan
   6. Setup cross-environment connectivity
   7. Test components and application functionality 
   8. Backup data and application
   9. Replicate application data
   10. Migrate application components
   11. Test
```